# Where are the sample files located in LINQPAD by default

Tags: linqpad

Where are the sample files located in LINQPAD by default?  In C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Roaming\LINQPad\Samples, I see some samples, but it didn't include the default samples. I want to find the folder which include "C# 4.0 in a nutshell" samples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The folder you mention is the location for additional sample libraries that you download. The built-in samples are included as an embedded resource within the LINQPad executable itself.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, is there any easy way to change the database connection for those embedded LINQ query. Right now, it's all use Nutshell.mdf in <ApplicationData>\LINQPad, is there any easy to change it point to another database on my machine. For example, .\SQLExpress.Nutshll